# nonlinear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I am interested in solving coupled differential equations with the following shape:

\begin{equation}
\ddot y_p(x) =\sum_{lmn=1}^N C(l,m,n,p)y_l (x)y_m (x)y_n(x)
\end{equation}
where $p=1\cdots N$. 
The coefficient $C(l,m,n,p)$ control the general coupling between the functions involved, and can be written as a combination of delta functions in in its arguments.

Are there formal solutions to such class of o.d.e.'s, or at least convenient ansatz to tackle the problem?

Comment: Could you expand a little to define how you are using the index $p$? Also, what is the nature of the $C(l,m,n,p)$?

Comment: I expanded the text; I wish it's more clear now